# Access User Windows authentication /active directory IIS asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, windows-authentication, identity

I have two sites...one is a regular webforms and the other is pretty much a duplicate of the site, but done in MVC4. The webforms site is getting the user identity like this:

*string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;*

This fills userId just fine.

When I tried to do the same in the MVC site, of course HttpContext is a Controller.HttpContext, not a System.Web.HttpContext; so I fully qualify the MVC version:

*string userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;*

Both sites are using the IIS development server and both sites have authentication mode="Windows" in the web.config.

I'm not sure what else to look for/do to get the MVC version working.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: I would think anyone with reading experience could glean that I'm referring to Microsoft's MVC platform simply because I'd mentioned WebForms before it. Also, the question is larded with only Microsoft references. On top of that, I'd mentioned "MVC4", which is specifically a Microsoft implementation. Next time I will spell every single word out so that nitpickers everywhere will happy and can move on with their lives.

Comment: And your analogy is way off...it's more like "calling Coke 'soda'"

Comment: Ok, I am able to get the user via Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"], but not via User.Identity.Name (empty) and I'm not sure why yet.

Comment: Frameworks do not implement MVC design pattern .. your code does (or doesn't).

Comment: Ok update...I've made the following changes and HttpContext.User.Identity.Name in the MVC project is now filled:

1. Right click the project and select "Use IISExpress"
2. Highlight the project in the solution and hit F4, then change Windows Authentication to "enabled" , then Forms Authentication to "disabled"
3. Insure the web.config has authentication mode="Windows" (not sure why this AND #2 need to be done)
4. Insure the controller action is ornamented with [Authorize]